# tsql command optimization

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a million rows in my table.
If RunId field = 37 for 100K records, 
then which of these two are faster

```
update _PECO_Detail set RunId = 37 where Runid <> 37
update _PECO_Detail set RunId = 37
```

Is 900K records already have RunId of 37, then would the first command be faster

```
update _PECO_Detail set RunId = 37 where Runid <> 37
update _PECO_Detail set RunId = 37
```

Index does exist on field RunId

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first is faster, because it only updates rows that are not `37` -- that is 900,000 rows by your description, but that is bettern than 1,000,000.  If there are no such rows, then the two would have pretty similar performance.

Updating large numbers of rows is expensive, due to locking and logging overheads.  SQL Server updates a row even when there are no changes, so filtering before updating is highly recommended.  Sometimes, it is more efficient to just recreate the table.

Comment: so no matter how little the number of rows that already have 37, it will be better performance overall to update via filter...… right?

Comment: I am not sure this is true.  But I am trying it out.  The command with the filter took more than 1 hour to run.  I stopped it.  Not I am trying the other way.  We'll see what happens....

Comment: @KamMistry . . . There might be some edge case.  If you have one value out of one million that is 37, perhaps the test is longer than the small overhead of updating an additional row.  Or, if the filter is more complex than an integer comparison.  But in general, filtering is better.